# JavaScript URL looper

Tags: javascript

I am trying create a page that will run some given URLs, in time this will be a database populated list of URLs loaded into an array. I have it working using some code I have altered, however I don't want it to keep looping, I just want it to stop once the list is complete.

So basically loads first URL, waits .5 of a second after the pages loads, then moves onto the next until the list of URLS is finished.

However, my code keeps looping. How do I prevent this?

```js
var urls1 =
[
 'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t1.cfm',
 'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t2.cfm',
 'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t3.cfm',
 'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t4.cfm',
 'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t5.cfm'
];

function showUrl1(idx)
{
 var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
 f1.onload = function()
 {
  var next = ++idx % urls1.length;
  setTimeout(function()
  {
   showUrl1(next);
  }, 500);
 }
 f1.src = urls1[idx];
}

function start()
{
 showUrl1(0);
}
```

```html
<iframe class="show1" id="f1" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: % returns the remainder.
So your next is reset to 0 in the 5th loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont showUrl when the list ends

```
function showUrl1(idx)
{
    var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
    f1.onload = function()
    {

        var next = idx === urls1.length? null: ++idx ;
        setTimeout(function()
        {   if(next != null){
              showUrl1(next);
            }

        }, 500);
    }
    f1.src = urls1[idx];
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much, the only thing i have to do now is to show the count in a div :)

Comment: @AdamWalters What count??

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's looping is because you're using the [remainder operator %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). Just check the to see if `next` is greater than or equal to the length and then don't call `setTimeout()`. I've changed the snippet so that you can see it output in the console but you should get the idea.

```js
var urls1 = [
  'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t1.cfm',
  'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t2.cfm',
  'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t3.cfm',
  'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t4.cfm',
  'http://localhost:8500/SupportTools/t5.cfm'
];

function showUrl1(idx) {

  if (idx >= urls1.length) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(urls1[idx]);
  var next = ++idx;
  setTimeout(function() {
    showUrl1(next);
  }, 500);


}

function start() {
  showUrl1(0);
}

start();
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much, the only thing i have to do now is to show the count in a div :)